# Ubuntu 12.04.1 Setup doesn't detect Windows 7 partition

Tags: 12.04, windows

I'm not really that of a linux pro, more of a noob. But i can handle console operations. Well, this is my system:

ASUS ZenBook Prime UX31A
256 GB ADATA MX11 SSD
Intel Core i5-3317U (Ivy-Bridge)

I have a fresh installation of Windows 7 Ultimate (not activated) on a 90 GB NTFS Partition on my SSD, the rest is unassigned. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 from an USB Stick (no CD-Drive...) created with Universal USB Installer 1.9.1.1. However I'm not givven the option 'Install alongside Windows', and when i choose 'other' it shows that 256 GB of 256 GB are unassigned (free) Memory.

os-prober gave me:
/dev/sda1/:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain

I also tried:
sudo dmraid -rE

and:
sudo apt-get remove dmraid

with no success... How can I install Ubuntu alongside Windows? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have you booted into Windows and written data, such as by installing programs or otherwise? If you have not written data the OS can be over looked by the installer.

Comment: I tried but with no success. Now I'm thinking theres some leftover partition table, since when I reinstalled Windows, there were several partitions like recovery and InstantBoot and so on which I simply deleted (Windows Installer). Is it possible to fix that, maybe with FixParts or similar? How do I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is what did the trick for me: Since GParted didnt find any partitions on my SSD, i ran FixParts [FixParts Page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) and it told me there were leftovers and if i want to delete them, which i did, and then i was able to see the partitions in gparted and the setup. Thanks guys (girls)!